# Angular JS + SharePoint List + Rest API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, sharepoint

Below is the simple task I want to do :

> 1)    Create a simple form – employee details form and use SharePoint list to save the data.
>
> 2)    You have to complete CRUD operations for that employee details by using angularjs and rest services. If you will use SharePoint list then you don’t need to write service code separately, REST API is already available for this.

So what I need to do is to communicate `SharePoint` list with `AngularJs` and `REST`. I am new to `AngularJs` , `Sharepoint` and `REST`. Tried to search on google but could not find same.

Comment: What have you tried yet ? It seems to me like a scholar exercise that you didn't solved on your own...

Comment: I tried with many tutorials, videos and articles but because i am new to all 3 i.e. Angular, Rest and SharePoint so could not able to collect it in working single application.

Comment: I Learned decent amount of angular js from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/637430/Angular-js-example-application, http://angularjs.org/, http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-controller-tutorial/ etc.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a nice and easy [article](http://saikiran78.wordpress.com/2014/01/17/getting-list-data-in-sharepoint-2013-using-rest-api-and-angular-js/) by Saikiran Sheshagiri, explaining how to get List Data in SharePoint 2013 using Rest api and AngularJS .

Found another great [article](http://www.jeremythake.com/2014/01/sharepoint-rest-api-to-host-web-with-angularjs-services/) by Jeremy Thake, explaining how to use REST API to Host Web with AngularJS Services.

Comment: I am not able to understand how will i manage code provided in jeremy article in files/solution ?

Comment: Also where i will use given code in Saikiran Sheshagiri article. that is controller code but do i need to create an asp.net application separate from sharepoint ?

Comment: in jeremy's example he stores the files on a host web environment(ie. asp.net), so the question is ,what kind of app you are writing? a hosted app or some kind of web-part that is hosted on SharePoint?

Comment: in SP you can create a client web part and use Saikiran Sheshagiri's code.
example on how to create client web part: http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/client-webpart-in-sharepoint-2013.html

Comment: I want it to be in asp.net application not the web part.

Comment: try this example also by Jeremy, he uses ASP.NET MVC with angularJS:
http://www.jeremythake.com/2013/10/sharepoint-hosted-app-with-rest-angularjs-for-mvc-javascript/

Comment: I tried to work on http://www.jeremythake.com/2013/10/sharepoint-hosted-app-with-rest-angularjs-for-mvc-javascript/ but getting an error on var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); line. SP is not defined. I Just created 2 files from given code 1. Html file 2. Js file. also i am not able to open the given project code in VS 2013. any extra thing i should have to open this project in VS 2013.

Comment: I Also tried Saikiran Post from http://saikiran78.wordpress.com/2014/01/17/getting-list-data-in-sharepoint-2013-using-rest-api-and-angular-js/ and created a sharepoint employee list on address http://mum-vhd-316/HR/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Employee')/items . now when i used  Saikiran code in separate asp.net application it is throwing error " No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3132' is therefore not allowed access. " Why this is coming because sharepoint list and asp.net application are from diff. domain. wht should i do nw?

Answer (score 0):

Try to take the problem separatly in that order :

> Create an interface with AngularJS, which will do what you need for the CRUD UI part.
>
> Create a SharePoint list as suggested, in order to save you entries.
>
> Plug the AngularJS routes to the SharePoint REST webservice in order to junction the UI with the data storage.

See https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/12/votr-part-5-angularjs-crud-restful-apis.html for first and last point, and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198245.aspx for the second.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I will try by using these links. will post my results soon.